# OCR enabled pdf through C#

Tags: c#, pdf, acrobat

I am using acrobat sdk to convert a image pdf to searchable text pdf, Can anyone help me out, I am stucked, i need to check whether a file is already OCR or not??

Answer (score 0):

you can try this sample to apply [OCR](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41709/How-To-Use-Office-2007-OCR-Using-C) to images in a pdf document

Comment: thanks dear, but i am using adobe professional SDk for it, and i want to know , how can i check first if the file is OCR'ed or not, i am able to OCR file, but i dont want to OCR the files which are already OCR'ed..